# Why is this answer spam deleted?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just failed an LQP review audit where I'm absolutely not sure why the post has been spam deleted:

[throttling SES message with SQS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070748/throttling-ses-message-with-sqs-and-lambda/64194848#64194848)

> [image]

The answer fits to the question, and it explains all relevant parts in the answer itself. I checked all the links (before clicking "Looks OK"), and all of them point to pages that are directly related to the problem and are good supplementary material. None of the pages contains the name of the author.

Imho, I did everything I should during review and I don't understand why this post has been spam deleted. This post has been used as an audit three times, and all three times it was failed.

Comment: There was [a spam wave of lumigo.io](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=lumigo), impossible to notice just from a single review...

Comment: So yeah. A stinker of an audit. When an answer has that many links I get cold feet myself and I tend to open the question outside of review.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check the About Us of the company that owns the site linked twice:

[image]

See the fourth team member?

Now check the username of the one posting the answer:

[image]

Comment: Fair enough. But am I really expected to check the team list on every site a link points to?

Comment: I don't know what's expected or not. I'm not blaming you for failing the audit. I have to say that when I follow links because I suspect spam, I try to be more or less thorough. In this case, it took me just one click, so it wasn't that deeply concealed. You said you looked for the name of the author, so you were looking for the same thing, right?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad audit. It doesn't take a particularlty deep examination to find the spam-connection, and the suspicious link is posted twice, which makes it even more attention grabbing.

Comment: I usually make a "Find in page" for parts of the authors name (in this case I searched for "Efi"). I usually also check the authors profile to see if it states a company name or a link. The author is on SO for a long time, he has several other good answers and questions. If I would check subpages on every linked page in review queues, that would probably blow up the review time significantly. Maybe I should ask a new question to get clarification on how detailed links should be checked in LQP.

Comment: I don't check every subpage, but if it's a company page and they have an "about us" of sorts, I take a look. This time, it paid off very quickly.

Comment: But yes, we are venturing on "another question" territory. This one was "why was this answer deleted as spam", which I think is already covered.

Comment: “Fair enough. But am I really expected to check the team list on every site a link points to?” - You should check the real question, every time, to make sure your making the best decision.  **That answer is suspiciously spammy, the fact it doesn’t quote a single sentence, activates my spam senses.**

Comment: @BDL this is only if you are going to approve the answer with Looks OK vote. For blatant non-answers where you recommend deletion, none of that is needed - typically for recommending deletion one doesn't even need to look at the question